# Why does geolocation in Chrome on my PC without WiFi return a different result than geo IP?

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation

My PC doesn't have GPS, WiFi or a mobile network chip, so it seems to me that using the IP geodatabase is the only option to determine location.

When I use one of the geo IP websites, they correctly report the city I live in, but both Chrome and Firefox return a different city about 15 km from my location.

Using what approach would they be getting this less accurate location?